# Laravel 5 Eloquent custom constructor not working

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, eloquent, overloading

I'm trying to get a custom constructor to work with a model extending an Eloquent model in Laravel 5.4
I already make sure to call the parent constructor, but it seems that nothing that I do takes any effect at all after that.

Here is my __construct function:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->users();
}
```

And here is the users() method:

```
public function users()
{
    $this->users = collect();

    foreach($this->employees as $employee) {
        $this->users = $this->users->push($employee->user);
    }

    $this->users = $this->users->unique();
}
```

In this example employee is a class that links a user to a store and also defines their jobs. However, it doesn't matter what I try to assign. I have also tried just assigning a garbage variable in the constructor with

```
$this->foo = 'bar';
```

or even trying to overwrite an attribute, such as

```
$this->name = 'foobar';
```

to no avail. I've also tried to simply switch the order of the code calling parent::__construct() before or after my code and nothing at all changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And how you call your model?

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code of your classes

Comment: can you post the code for `parent::__construct()` ?

Comment: what are you doing that you expect to see these 'properties'/attributes? a dump, serialization ?

Comment: have you tried die dumping an instance of that object? I'm also interested at seeing the part before `__construct`, you might be extending a wrong class or reference.

Answer (score 0):

If changes in your child class are not showing up, even when you load garbage into it, it sounds like it to me that you might not be loading the right class into the context?

Perhaps check your `use` statements at the top to make sure you loaded the child class and not the parent. It would be easy not to notice, since they share the same interface, no syntax error would be called inherently.

If that's all OK, then I would check the logs for anything suspicious (e.g. error messages related to the function).

As well, it's very useful to use the `dd()` function along the execution chain to see the type and contents of your variables. You may find it being overridden at some unexpected point.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm an idiot, basically. The constructor functionality was working perfectly. My problem was I was trying to set attributes not on a new instance of a class, but after retrieving it, which worked out better by just using the getAttribute methods.

Thank you everyone for trying to help, but it was just me being dumb.